# Cannot Convert type System.IO.Streamreader to double

Tags: c#

I have to load a text file from the system and I am getting the following error:

> Cannot Convert type System.IO.Streamreader to double

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Double num1;
        int  num2;
        Double  mul;
        Double div;
        Double result;
        Double conv;

        // this we are adding m3 size using int num1
        Console.WriteLine("What is M3 Size");
        num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        // now we are adding buying price using number 2
        Console.WriteLine("What is buying price");
        num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\conversion.txt");
        conv = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\conversion.txt");

        div = num2 / conv;
        mul = num1 * 128;
        result = div + mul;

        Console.WriteLine(" \n\nC&F $ {0}", result);

        Console.ReadLine();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: For future questions please keep in mind that your question does not require a backstory about the company or yourself. It should contain 3 points: Describe the problem (including error message), your attempts so far and the expected + actual output. Most other things are clutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The streamreader is just the reader, you actually need to .Read() to get at the file

```
using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\blabla.txt"))
{
    //Create a reader - the using ensures that the system cleans up when we're done.

    //Read the whole file as a single string
    string fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();

    //Parse the string to a double
    double conv= Double.Parse(fileContents);

 }
```

Comment: Really, it should be `Dispose`d, ideally in a `using` block. It's never too early to start learning good practices.

Comment: Thanks alot you guys responded too quick, appreciate it alot.Now if i use this im getting this error "namespace TextReader could not be found are you missing assembly ref, and to StreamReader as well"

Answer (score 0):

You declare the variable `conv` as a `double`, but then try to assign a `StreamReader` to it.

Read up on how to use [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at the provided MSDN article.

Comment: Yes because if i cant describe it to double it cant get / by double because i need decimal values too so there is no option left for me instead of describing it as double